# Haskell data structure with O(1) indexing/updating and O(logn) cons

Tags: haskell, data-structures, time-complexity, immutability

Currently I need an *immutable* data structure (indexed by `Int`) that has fast read and update (basically, effectively O(1)), but somewhat slower cons (such as O(logn)) is acceptable. Other operations are not necessary. What I have now are:

- `Data.IntMap` which is a radix tree. It has asymptotic O(1) for everything and is currently the best choice.
- `Data.Sequence` which is a finger tree. It has worst-case O(logn) lookup/update but O(1) cons. That is not quite in line with my need and indeed performs worse then `IntMap`s in my microbenchmarks.
- `Data.HashMap` has O(logn) for everything and performs worse than `IntMap`.

My question is: is there any Haskell data structures that can perform better than `IntMap` in this regard?

Comment: Do you mean appending a single element to the right or appending two large structures? `Data.Sequence.><` is O(log n) and not O(1), so I assume you mean appending a single element, but please update your question to make that clearer.

Comment: A potential idea to look into is version trees of arrays like https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/papers/farray/popl17.pdf and related work.

Comment: @Noughtmare, yes, if `n` is the length of the *shorter* sequence (plus 2 to be overly picky about edge cases).

Comment: So you want to add an element on the left (cons)? Or on the right (snoc)?

Comment: FYI: The `Data.HashMap` code could be manually specialized to `Int` keys, which would produce a data structure much more competitive with `IntMap` (maybe better, depending on degree of persistence used, reads vs. writes, etc.). Using stock `HashMap`, each `Int` key is stored (completely redundantly) as a pointer to a heap object that is (uselessly) accessed on read or write and that also burns up GC time.

Comment: The O(1) vs. O(log n) claims for `IntMap` vs. `HashMap` are of no significance whatsoever. They're really *both* radix trees; they just have different branching factors and `HashMap` is polymorphic in key type.

Comment: You should be able to make either `IntMap` or `HashMap` more efficient for your purpose by writing versions that take advantage of the fact that your keys are all consecutive.

Comment: You may be interested to try https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-hashtables

Comment: @dfeuer How can `IntMap` be optimized for consecutive indices? It'll be nice if you could write an answer or give some directions.

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn It seems that this is a mutable data structure - so it doesn't quite satisfies what the question requires.

Comment: sorry, missed the immutability bit.

Comment: You should be able to do something like `data Arr a = Arr { size :: !Word, arrArr :: !(Arr' a) }` with `data Arr' a = Bin !(Arr' a) !(Arr' a) | Tip a | Nil`. You'll always insert at the leftmost empty spot, until you hit a power of 2 size (see `Data.Bits.popCount`), at which point you'll build a `Bin` with the old tree to the left. Plenty of details left for you to work out, and I can't guarantee I've got it right. The real point is that when you build your trie, the tree shape is fully determined by the number of elements, so you don't need to store any extra shape info in the nodes.

Comment: That should save you about `3n` words, improving cache utilization and reducing GC times.

Comment: The same kind of deal goes for `HashMap`. Non-full nodes won't need bitmaps to say what matches to what, because it's always consecutive from zero. And the leaves become just values, not key/hash/value triples. And the collision buckets go away.

Comment: @dfeuer Determining the tree shape from the length involves recursively finding the most significant set bit and unset that bit. Do you think this will hurt performance?

Comment: When you're looking up/updating, you can find the high bit once (`countLeadingZeros` and a simple shift) and then you don't need to find it again. For `snoc`, I think things are also reasonably simple. Unless the tree size is a power of two, you always start stepping down to the right. As you do so, keep track of how many elements are to the left of you. I think you'll need to find the high bit just once to do that, and then keep track of the subtree size at your level as you step down.

Comment: @dfeuer For lookup/update, the tree will always have a full left subtree (this recursively applies to all subtrees) therefore for that case I can just track down each bit. However the right subtree's shape is determined by the length (e.g. the length `100010` means the right subtree's common prefix is `1000`, and that subtree's right subtree's common prefix is `10`, etc). So for any case looking up down the right subtree I'll need to repeatedly find the high bit, 2nd highest bit etc. I'll try to implement this sometime this week, and see how it performs.

Comment: For `snoc`, I can just `bit . popCount` and then shift 1 to the right down each left subtree, until I hit `2` where I can insert a new subtree there with the original subtree on the right.

Comment: I think I made a mistake. It should just be a complete tree.